# MS Access: Insert rows from an source table where the rows don't exist in the target table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, sql-insert

The question of inserting records that don't exist has been answered in various forms in many other posts.  However, this particular condition hasn't been address (at least not as far I can tell... and I've looked hard.)  I'm not new to Access or to SQL so I feel like I've tried all the obvious stuff... but I might be missing something.

I am attempting to insert new records from a source table into a target table.  The structure of the source table is an exact replica of the target table; but the source table may have additional records that are not in the target table.  Both tables have an autonumber 'id' column.  Here's the structure of both tables:

```
'id' autonumber, pk
'equip_number' (text)
'permit_type_id' (text)  

INSERT INTO permit (equip_number, permit_type_id)
  SELECT f.equip_number, f.permit_type_id 
  FROM temp_permit AS f 
  WHERE Not Exists (
    SELECT 1 FROM permit AS o 
    WHERE o.equip_number = f.equip_number AND o.permit_type_id = f.permit_type_id)
```

Neither the equip_number nor the permit_type_id are unique, but the combination of the equip_number plus the permit_type_id is always unique, i.e, each piece of equipment may have many permit types.

When I run the query, I get an error, "... didn't add (2) records to the table due to key violations...."  There are exactly two new records in the source file so this is telling me that all inserts failed.  I have tested the subquery and it returns exactly the two new records, so that appears to be working fine.  I have confirmed that those two records do not exist in the target table.

Here's a screenshot of the target 'permit' table in design view. Both tables are identical, i.e., the source table is an exact copy of this table.

[image: permit_table_struct.png]

Comment: Check the PK constraint definitions carefully, it could be that there are 2 unique indexes on each column of the target tables. Access does not make it easy to list all constraints though.

Comment: Thanks, NoChance. The 'id' columns in both tables are autonumber and "Indexed (No Duplicates)".  The other two data columns have no relevant constraints.  But since I'm not selecting the 'id' column from the source table shouldn't Access just add the new records with an autonumbered 'id' value in the target table?

Comment: There are 2 points. First, you must have a single composite PK this is not the same as having 2 separte PKs. Second point, you should not include autonum columns in the insert statement when the table has data. At least this is as far as I remember...

Comment: Check if fields are required. Test the entire select query of insert statement not just subquery. Does it return empty records or one empty field? Are there other fields in target table that might be required?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the target 'permit' table in design view. Both tables are identical, i.e., the source table is an exact copy of this table.

Comment: Ran out of editing time... here is the screenshot....

<img src="http://signalok.com/images/permit_table_struct.png">

Comment: Thanks, Parfait, I have tested the entire SELECT and it returns all and only the two new records from the source table that it should return.  I have tried running the INSERT both with and without including the 'id' key column in the SELECT clause but I get the same result no matter which.

Comment: FWIW, if I demote the 'id' column from being a pk to just an autonumber field, the INSERT query works fine, i.e., the two new records are brought over.  However, it also brings over the 'id' field values, resulting in duplicate 'id' values in the target table.

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue using the test database [here](http://wikisend.com/download/396780/so34553177.accdb). Note that the tables also have a unique index on ([equip_number], [permit_type_id]) and I still don't get a "key violations" error using the INSERT query in your question. I'm also confused when you say that "it also brings over the 'id' field values" when [id] is not included in the column list for the INSERT. There's something else going on that you're not telling us.

Comment: (Also, when posting a reply to an earlier comment remember to use the "at sign" - e.g., @Parfait - so the commenter will be notified.)

Comment: Thanks, @GordThompson.  I looked at the db you sent. It's accurate... and I see that it works. So I tried coping my tables into your db and the query worked. While copying, I realized that there was something I didn't think to mention before, namely that the target 'permit' table is a linked table while the source 'temp_permit' table is not a linked table. So I copied the linked table into the db and the query worked.  Obviously (?) the linked table is identical to the table it's linked to, so nothing should have changed when I copied it directly into the db? The query shouldn't care, right?

Comment: @GordThompson, you probably knew this was coming, but I also just tested your db by creating another db, copying the 'permit' table to the new db and then linking the 'permit' table.  The query still works.  Could this be some kind of table corruption?

Comment: *"Could this be some kind of table corruption?"* - It could be. Try doing a [Compact and Repair Database](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Compact-and-repair-a-database-6EE60F16-AED0-40AC-BF22-85FA9F4005B2) operation on the database file containing the [permit] table.

Comment: Thanks, @GordThompson, good suggestion... I should have tried.  Just did.  Regrettably, C&R didn't fix it.  I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: Open the database containing the [permit] table and see if [permit] is involved in any Relationships with another table in that database. If so, verify that the rows you are trying to insert would not violate any referential integrity constraints that those Relationships might impose.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to donate your gray matter to this, @GordThompson. Nope... no relationships.

Comment: Perhaps try deleting and re-creating the table link to [permit] in the other database.

Comment: Yes, @GordThompson, that's what I finally had to do.  There were several tables in the source file that had somehow become corrupted in a way that was undetectable accept that their indexes didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @GordThompson!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue here was that the linked table definitions for the destination table contained outdated (or perhaps corrupted) information about the indexes on that table. Deleting and re-creating the table links solved the problem.